# Decoding logs of Approval event with web3js results in error

Tags: web3js, erc-721, events, logs

I am trying to decode the Approval event of an ERC721 contract.
I fetch the logs for the contract with the alchemy API and then try to decode them
with web3js.
The code looks like this:

```
const logs = await alchemy.core.getLogs({
  address: contractAddress,
  topics: ["0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925"],
  fromBlock: firstNumber,
  toBlock: secondNumber
})


for(let key in logs){
  const data = logs[key].data
  const topics = logs[key].topics

let result = web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(
  [
    {type: 'address', name: 'owner', indexed: true}, 
    {type: 'address', name:'approved', indexed: true},
    {type: 'uint256', name:'tokenId', indexed: true},
  ],
  [data],
  topics
)}
```

This results in the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) null: value out of range (argument="value", value=20, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0)

I tried to use toString() on the data and the topic before, as it worked with decoding other events, but this resulted in this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="{topic values}", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0

Looking at the **data** and **topics** I get from the logs, I noticed that data always is just **0x**. The topics are the actual value.
Looking up the transactions on etherscan I also noticed that the data value is also **0x** so that seems correct?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if the field is indexed then it goes in the `Topics` array at position 1,2 or 3. At the position 0 goes the event signature hash. So if it is an address, it will be in the lower side (right) of the 32 bytes of the topic. `Data` field is used only for event fields that are not indexed

Comment: So what would be the solution? deleting the data field does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here.

When you retrieve the logs, you receive an array of different elements. Let's take the Approval event from an ERC-721 contract as an example since it's what you need.

In this case, this is how it looks in the smart contract:

```
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed approved, uint256 indexed tokenId);
```

As you can see, this event has 3 indexed parameters, which means that those values will be returned into the `topics` array in the logs object. You can only mark up to 3 elements as `indexed`; the non-indexed parameters will be returned in a separate array named `data`.

> You ask: Looking at the data and topics I get from the logs, I noticed that data always is just 0x. The topics are the actual value. Looking up the transactions on etherscan I also noticed that the data value is also 0x, so that seems correct?
>
> This is the case because all parameters are indexed in the Approval event, so the `data` array is returned empty as `0x`.

A typical `topics` array for the approval event looks like this:

```sh
topics: [
      '0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925', // Event signature
      '0x000000000000000000000000f9cc4b93728328ccfce3cfe446d4c52d1571aa20', // Owner address
      '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', // Approved address
      '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043c' // Token ID
    ],
```

As you can see, there are 4 elements because the first element is the event signature (like you have in your code). The last 3 elements correspond to what's returned by the event:

- Address owner
- Address approved
- Token ID

These elements are encoded as 32-byte size, and to take the addresses, you have to take the last 20 bytes; in this case, the last 20 bytes equal to the last 40 characters as they are in hex format 2 hex digits make up one byte.

> Note that you have to add 0x in front of those 20 bytes to parse a valid address

I'm not very familiar with the Alchemy SDK, but here is a script in `web3.js` to retrieve and parse the `Approval` event from an ERC-721 contract using the [getPastLogs](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/ethereum/eth_getlogs) method.

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
require('dotenv').config();

// Initialize connection to the node. 
const node_url = process.env.ETHEREUM_CHAINSTACK;
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(node_url))

// Retrieve the logs based on the Transfer event
async function getLogs() {
    
    // Initialize blocks to query
    const startBlock = 16599340
    const latestBlock = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()    

    // Set the parameters for the getPastLogs method
    const params = {
        fromBlock: startBlock,
        toBlock: 'latest',
        address: "0x9401518f4EBBA857BAA879D9f76E1Cc8b31ed197", // smart contract address
        topics: ["0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925"], // Approval event signature
    };

    // Print some info on the screen.
    console.log(`Getting logs starting from block ${startBlock} to ${latestBlock} \n`)

    // Retrieve logs
    const logs = await web3.eth.getPastLogs(params)
    //console.log(logs)     
    
    return logs
}

// Parse the logs and extract only the tx hash and topics.
async function parseLogs(logs) {

    for (let object of logs) {

        const txhash = object.transactionHash
        const from = object.topics[1]
        const fromAddress = from.slice(-40); // This is how we take the last 20 bytes

        const to = object.topics[2]
        const toAddress = to.slice(-40);

        const tokenId = object.topics[3]

        console.log(`Approval tx hash: ${txhash}`)
        console.log(`Owner address: 0x${fromAddress}`)
        console.log(`Approved address: 0x${toAddress}`)

        console.log(`Token ID: ${web3.utils.hexToNumber(tokenId)} \n`) // web3.utils.hexToNumber converts to the decimal token id
    }
}

// Main program.
async function main() {
    const approvalLogs = await getLogs()
    parseLogs(approvalLogs)
}

main();
```

Everything in the `getLogs` function is similar to what you already do. The `parseLogs` function extracts the topics, decodes them, and prints them on the screen.

Running it will give you something like this:

```sh
Getting logs starting from block 16600272 to 16600472

Approval tx hash: 0x7dee982e52154f0750f58ce77bcc6047c08d38339ade1a060e317eccd17f3b6c
Owner address: 0xf9cc4b93728328ccfce3cfe446d4c52d1571aa20
Approved address: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Token ID: 1084

Approval tx hash: 0xfe319b5527fd4f9a240abc0d0676599251e1ce58fa87a45eb674a9e39862ddf3
Owner address: 0x2ed0f4e9769591d8eff038abd884187c8101c7f3
Approved address: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Token ID: 828
```